# How to make SuggestBox (GWT) to suggest using only the first word of the suggestion?

Tags: java, gwt, suggestbox

My title may be a bit fuzzy but I want to make my suggestbox to suggest words like 
this when I type letters into the textbox:

Letter typed in suggestbox: A

**A** lpaca

**A** pple

**A** rgon

**NOT** like this:

Letter typed in suggestbox:A

**A** lpaca  **a** cute

**A** pple  **a** nion

**A** rgon  **a** ttire

is there any way to make the suggest box to behave like this?
I just want the first word couple of words that matches the letter, not including the
string with multiple words.

I am using GWT in Eclipse by the way.

EDIT: I suck at formatting, the words are

Alpaca

Apple

Argon

---

Alpaca acute

Apple anion

### Argon attire

EDIT AGAIN:
I want them to be appear like this:

Entry: Exec

Suggestion:

Execute

Execution

Executor

Entry: Execution t

Suggestion:

Execution time

Execution timer

Execution title

Basically I want it to work like google searches, where the multiple worded suggestions won't appear as long as I haven't typed a second word.

Comment: Are you using any of the GWT frameworks like SmartGWT or something?

Comment: I think you have to create your own version of SuggestOracle.

Comment: @biplav just the gwt plugin for eclipse indigo, which can be downloaded in the Install New Software.

Comment: Have you checked this? http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.DefaultSuggestionDisplay.html You might override showSuggestions to exclude/filter.

Comment: so you would like to ignore all words which appear after first "space" ? If is that you can prepare your list of strings before adding it to MultiWordOracle. For every string, leave only the first word.

Comment: @biplav, I'm currently sifting through it, thanks.

Comment: @fascynacja, not really ignore, but I don't want multiple words to appear if I haven't typed in them yet, 

ex: Input> E,

result>

Execute

Etc.

Input>Execution tim,

result>

Execution time

Execution timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extending SuggestOracle is the way to go! Please check the code below... Once your implementation is correct, pass a new instance of your oracle to your SuggestBox.

`s.startsWith(userInput)` answers the core of your needs. But you can write other conditions of course.

```
   public class MySuggestOracle extends SuggestOracle {

        private List<String> data;

        public MySuggestOracle(List<String> data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public void requestSuggestions(final Request request, final Callback callback) {
            String userInput = request.getQuery();
            List<Suggestion> suggestions = new LinkedList<Suggestion>();
            for (final String s : data) {
                if (s.startsWith(userInput)) {
                    suggestions.add(new Suggestion() {
                        @Override
                        public String getReplacementString() {
                            return s;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public String getDisplayString() {
                            return s;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            Response response = new Response(suggestions);
            callback.onSuggestionsReady(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you help me on how I can implement this on my suggestbox? I am using a custom suggestbox class which I extended from suggestbox.

Comment: Turns out I have to put MultiWordSuggestions to my codebase and comment out the requestSuggestions method in it, thanks.

Comment: Hi, glad you found a workaround during the week-end !

Comment: I will not be able to get any result from String userInput = request.getQuery();  What can be the issue??